# Eclipse - How to select source folder for new file?

Tags: eclipse

I just downloaded Eclipse Juno release a couple of days ago.  I started a new PHP project.  When I create a new file, it makes me select the root folder of the project as the source... Is there any way that I could select sub-directories within the project's root folder as the file's source folder?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse with the [PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt) plugin?

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a new PHP project if you don't want the files you're creating in that folder. There is no such thing as sub-directories in Eclipse. It creates seperate directories and you just go to wherever you're storing the files and transfer them to your server by going into your htdocs and dragging the folder and placing the folder into the one on your server that you want it to be in. I hope this has helped you.

Comment: Either you or I have completely misunderstood the question and saying that "There is no such thing as sub-directories in Eclipse." is just not correct. An Eclipse project uses the folder structure on the file system so of course there are sub-directories.

Comment: You can't do that. You have to make a new project each time. He's wondering if you can create a project folder within another project folder within the Eclipse interface. Not posible